# How to transfer data from * .ejs file to app.js and handle click event on HTML tag on app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm learning Node.js, EJS, MongoDB, Mongoose and Express, so I decided to build a small application that applied the knowledge I was learning. You can follow my project details in this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-lichterman-w7fgg (extremely sorry because my project does not work on this page, I just posted here for you to understand my project most accurately by because I code it on my computer)

This is the image I took when my application ran locally: 
[image]

I want that when I hit Delete, it erases the entire 'Tiếng anh Sơ cấp' area,  In the views/home.ejs file, from line number 13 to line number 17, I've built like this:[image] and now I don't really know how to transfer data from this home.ejs file to app.js and how to capture click event on this anchor tag like. Please help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add this delete method in your app.js file then in your ejs template file add that URL in an anchor tag with id and you can get that id using req.params.id in app.js file

```
//.ejs file
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/delete/any_id">Delete</a>

//app.js
app.get('/delete:id', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params.id);
   // Add your delete functionality here using this id
})
```